# Is there a way to download package resources after installing the package in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, resources

I am trying to make a python package. The package basically retrieves data from `the Bible` in db format. I have around 5 resource files (the database files) that I access. I don't want to package them with the python code. The python code is less than 10 kb but the resource files are more than 60 mb and it might increase if I add any more Bibles.

Is there a formal way to let the package download the databases from a website? I have the databases uploaded in github. Is there a way to download the databases from there?

What is the best way to go about doing this?

P.S: Others who might install the package should be able to download these files too

Comment: Did you finally succeed? I'm looking for the same trick. Thx

Comment: I wrote a separate script to download resources. If resources are missing, my main python file calls that script internally and gets the needed resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a much longer search as usual (~1h), I found the following that does the trick.

1. Move your data from your PyPi project to an external website.
2. Insert `download` in the `requires` list in `setup.py`
3. Insert this where you need data in your pkg code:

> ```
> from download import download
>
> download("https://your-external-website/data", "path/dl_file")
> ```